# Are attributes defined using force_override in a Chef recipe visible for subsequent recipes of the cookbook?

Tags: chef-infra, infrastructure-as-code

When looking through the documentation of Chef I saw the attribute precedence rules used in Chef. However, now I am wondering whether an attribute defined using `force_override` also can potentially override the same attribute used in a subsequent recipe of the cookbook which is defined using `normal` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Yes, as setting an attribute at normal level won't change the resulting attribute on the node object if it is already set by a force_override level.